# Get error when running Coverall.io (.net 1.3.4) on AppVeyor (Default Azure Environment)

Tags: coveralls, appveyor

Looks like this is an environment issue, when I run the coverall tool and the AppVeyor server says it doesn't contain the Azure `TableEntity` under the Jenkins workspace.

```
packages\coveralls.io.1.3.4\tools\coveralls.net.exe --opencover coverage.xml
An unknown exception has occurred.
Could not find a part of the path 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\Common\Table\TableEntity.cs'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Coveralls.Net.LocalFileSystem.ComputeHash(String path) in c:\projects\coveralls-net-gmbph\coveralls.net\LocalFileSystem.cs:line 27
   at Coveralls.CoverallsBootstrap.get_CoverageFiles() in c:\projects\coveralls-net-gmbph\Coveralls.Lib\CoverallsBootstrap.cs:line 124
   at Coveralls.Net.Program.Run(CommandLineOptions options) in c:\projects\coveralls-net-gmbph\coveralls.net\Program.cs:line 40
   at Coveralls.Net.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\projects\coveralls-net-gmbph\coveralls.net\Program.cs:line 18
Command exited with code 1
```

https://ci.appveyor.com/project/TianyuanC/dals/build/1.0.54

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Apparently, according to the source of this tool it parses the XML and does something with its paths. When it finds invalid paths, it throws that error. So the solution is to simply filter out only the assemblies that you need in your call to OpenCover (or whatever tool you are using along with coveralls). They won't be in the `coverage.xml`, hence they won't be acted upon.

For more information on OpenCover filters (because it's the most common scenario for AppVayor + Coverall), check [here](https://github.com/opencover/opencover/blob/master/main/OpenCover.Documentation/Usage.pdf).